# How to switch RenderAction via jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have navigation panel with two tabs tab1 and tab2

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Text 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Text 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("_ViewPartial", "Func1");}
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("_ViewPartial", "Func2");}
    </div>
</div>
```

The question is how to switch between two RenderActions clicking on tabs to render partial view dynamically. `("_ViewPartial", "Func1")` loaded by default.

Comment: How did you want to do this?  *render* both then quickly switch using js/jquery (as per your code) or only render one then render the other when the tab changes (as per your question)?   Have you considered a 3rd party tab plugin that does this for you?

Comment: @freedomn-m First loaded ("_ViewPartial", "Func1") tabs-1 is active. Then when I click tabs-2 ("_ViewPartial", "Func2") loaded. Clicking tabs-1 returns to default value. The first case is appropriate "render both then quickly switch using js/jquery"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching tabs using js with active class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233418/switching-tabs-using-js-with-active-class)

Comment: @freedomn-m I know how to switch tabs with links, I can't switch RenderActions.

Comment: Hence the question.  Which you answered that you wanted to *render both* then switch with js.

Comment: To load the content from your controller via ajax, use: `$("#tab-content").load("@Url.Action("Func2")")`